# Limitar Caracteres mientras función copia caracteres a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

**Tengo el siguiente codigo:**

código html:

```
<input type="text" id="Div5" placeholder="Nombre Asignatura" onkeyup="fAgrega();" title="Introduzca nombre para asignatura" required/>

<input type="text" id="Div6" onChange="valida_longitud()"  title="Introduzca las siglas de la asignatura" required/>
</form>
```

Este código lo utilizo para pasar de un input a otro lo que se escribe:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >function fAgrega()
{
document.getElementById("Div6").value = document.getElementById("Div5").value;
} 
</script>
```

para mejor especificación al momento de copiarse los caracteres estos no excedan un maximo de 3 caracteres,

**El siguiente código:**
este código lo utilizo para capturar lo que se copia e intentar no exceder un máximo de 3 caracteres del input que recibe lo que se va a copiar.

```
<script>
contenido_input = ""
num_caracteres_permitidos = 3

function valida_longitud(){
   num_caracteres = document.forms['textos'].texto.value.length

   if (num_caracteres > num_caracteres_permitidos){
      document.forms['textos'].texto.value = contenido_input
   }else{
      contenido_input = document.forms['textos'].texto.value
   }


}

</script>
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Te adjunto una respuesta que dí a otra pregunta similar a la tuya. En ese caso preguntaban por PHP. Sin embargo, te recomiendo el uso de utilizar un lenguaje en el lado del servidor (como es PHP) ya que el código en el lado del cliente se puede llegar a modificar.

Comment: hola francisco muchas gracias revisare tu informacion para ver si puede ayudarme

Comment: Lo que quieres lograr es que el usuario no pueda pegar valores mayores al largo permitido? Solamente quieres realizar este control al pegar datos o también al ingresar caracter a caracter?

Comment: Hola @Marcos Martinez te explico lo que quiero lograr es que por ejemplo: si notas cuando el usuario escribe en el primer id Div5 , al mismo tiempo se va copiando en el id Div6, entonces lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se este copiando no exceda los 3 caracteres manualmente se que puedo hacelro con html solo indicando el maxLength

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente especifigar el tamaño máximo con *maxLength*

```js
var i = document.querySelector('input')

i.onchange = function(e)
{
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.value))
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="3" /><br />
```

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, se acerca del maxLength, pero para mejor especificación al momento de copiarse los caracteres en el Div6 , estos caracteres que se vallan copiando no excedan los 3 caracteres,

Answer (score 0):

La verdad a mi no me gusta trabajar con Javascript, para limitar los valores  introducidos en un INPUT uso el atributlo **maxlength** el cual pertenece a HTML.
Ejemplo:

```
<form>
<input type="text" maxlength="3">
</form>
```

Sin embargo, esto puede ser modificado, te recomiendo que trabajes con PHP

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respueta pero ,a idea es, para mejor especificación al momento de copiarse los caracteres en el Div6 , estos caracteres que se vallan copiando no excedan los 3 caracteres,

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, de todos modos el campo de texto A FUERZA no permitirá mas de 3. Explicate por favor

Comment: Hola @Flavio C. Siria , exacto la idea es que mientras se copia no exceda los 3 caracteres.